# Python sort strings in a list of strings by 3 last characters and a number

Tags: python, sorting

I've a list of strings as following:

```
input = ['foobaraaa1', 'foobaraab1', 'foobaraac1', 'foobaraaa2', 'foobaraab2', 'foobaraacc']
```

I need to sort it descending by last 4 characters and a rule that `numbers < letters` and print first output

In this case I'd need the output to be `foobaraacc`

my code looks like:

```
print((f'Latest Released Firmware SM-J400F: ' + sorted(result,key=lambda x: (x[::-4], len(x)),reverse=True)[0]))
```

But it is not working as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your key function is… strange. Why did you put `len(x)` there? IMHO this should be enough:

```
print((f'Latest Released Firmware SM-J400F: ' + sorted(result,key=lambda x: x[-4:],reverse=True)[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you sir that works :-). I am fairly new to python.